# How to change input background colour of form?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a form, wpcf7, which loads a light blue box background color when content is entered into it which has been entered before. For example, my device remembers my address and, as soon as I start typing, it suggest entering the whole thing automatically which, if I do, it turns rhe background color blue. If I enter it manually, however, the background just stays white. So how do I make the background-color E6f7ff whenever data is entered, preloaded or not.

Tried css.

`.input.wpcf7-form-control:active {background-color: #E6f7ff;}`

Didn't work.

Html:

```
<label> Your Name (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" 
name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7- 
text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria- 
invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Email (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" 
name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates- 
as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> 
</label></p>
<p><label> Subject<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input 
type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7- 
form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Message<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea 
name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><div class="anr_captcha_field"><div id="anr_captcha_field_1" 
class="anr_captcha_field_div"></div></div><span class="wpcf7-form- 
control-wrap g-recaptcha-response"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>. 
</div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        </footer><!-- .
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/contact-us/

Comment: you targeted elements that have two *classes*: `input` and `wpcf7-form-control`. If you're just targeting inputs with the one class, remove the `.` preceding the `input` in your selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong CSS pseudo-class. Instead of `:active` you will need:

```
.input.wpcf7-form-control:focus
```

alternatively you can use the `:focus-within` pseudo-class

I have tried this CSS rule on your page:

```
form input:focus, form textarea:focus {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and it worked for each element except the Email. If I added `!important`, then it worked for the email as well.

Comment: @One89 you are welcome. Please let me know of the result.

Comment: So I tried manually entering the text and the boxes don't automatically turn blue on entry. Is there something I should add to the selector? Thanks.

Comment: @One89 thanks for the feedback, I added further information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks dude. Amazing. Works perfectly. Just how to keep it blue after deselect-until it's sent?

Comment: @One89 for that case you might need a class to define the background color. And then you can add that class to the item via Javascript on focus event. You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp If my answer answered your question, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: That's great. Thanks so much. Marked correct and tried to upvote you but have less than 15 reputation so won't let me :-( next time.... :-)

Comment: @One89 no problem. Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: Yes sir. Over and out :-)